# How to create application module in feathers.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, configure, reusability, feathersjs

I want to build an application that could contain many modules. I want to build the application in a reusable yet configurable way that I could specify which modules are enabled based on the npm package configuration.

For example, my application is about an ERP system.
An ERP system may have HR, PayRoll, Sales etc modules. I want to achieve the above with feathers JS.

I checked out https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#sub-apps but its unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Feathers generator](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/generators/readme.html) already sets every service you create up to be configurable individually. Each service [e.g. the chat message service](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/tree/master/src/services/messages) is self contained. Just as the [generator sets it up](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/services/index.js) it can be required and then added via an `app.configure` call (which can also be conditional).

Comment: I am trying to use the graphql for my application with MongoDB as database. What I want to do is, create a basic app with employees. Then create a module for HR, where I could add HR related functionality, graphql schema and mongodb migrations. And then require in the app when I want to use this module. Or else the app could be just about sales and users (employees) in the app will be sales representatives. And products module along with it to know which products they sold, etc. Is that something feathers could help with?

Comment: The use case of feathers is just to leverage the "real time" reflections of inventory and other changes. I am looking for concept of "packaging" here.

Comment: It is mostly up to you. You can bundle services into their own modules or create individual "microservice" applications that run parts of your application. Some more pointers on distributing/scaling can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076627/evaluating-featherjs-authentication-needs/41095638#41095638